# Save image to Documents directory than load it into UIImageView

Tags: ios, uiimageview, uiimage, save, load

I have been trying to solve this issue since days. I have an app where the user selects an image than the selected image is saved to the disk and later loaded into a UIImageView, however this does not work, no matter what I try. i have made a small app just to test this, and it does not work there either. The imageView stays blank. Here is my code:

```
@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (IBAction)button:(id)sender {
    UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    picker.allowsEditing = NO;
    picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
    [self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:nil];

}

-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info{
    UIImage *selectedImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
    [self saveImage:selectedImage];
    self.imageView.image = [self loadImage];
    [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];

}

- (void)saveImage: (UIImage*)image
{
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,
                                                         NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString* path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:
                      @"image.png" ];
    NSData* data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);
    [data writeToFile:path atomically:YES];
}


- (UIImage*)loadImage
{
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,
                                                         NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString* path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:
                      @"image.png" ];
    UIImage* image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:path];
    return image;
}

@end
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to add the delegate of the `UIImagePickerController` so that following code solve you problem.

```
- (IBAction)button:(id)sender {
    UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    picker.allowsEditing = NO;
    picker.delegate = self;
    picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
    [self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Now, In .h file use following code.

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController<UINavigationControllerDelegate,UIImagePickerControllerDelegate>
@property(nonatomic,weak)IBOutlet UIImageView *imageView;

@end
```

Comment: You just need to delegate the of `UIImagePickerController `.

Comment: Yeah..thanks. I feel ashamed now...such a noob mistake. You just saved my project. Thank you!! :))